# Measure performace of C++ test suite with Hudson

Tags: c++, hudson, hudson-plugins, cppunit

I am using CppUnit plugin for Hudson to read my test results. How can I measure performance, in terms of run-time of my tests, and show them on my Hudson dashboard? Any plugins, or hacks would be of great help.

Thanks!